# Multiple digital clocks with js & html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to run two digital clocks using JavaScript and svg embedded in html, on a single html page. I have one clock working:

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(n) {
  for (var r = this.toString(); r.length < n; r = 0 + r);
  return r;
};
function updateClock() {
  let now = new Date();
  let sec = now.getSeconds();
  let min = now.getMinutes();
  let hou = now.getHours();
  let mo = now.getMonth();
  let dy = now.getDate();
    let day = now.getDay();
  let shortYear = now.getFullYear();
  let yr = shortYear.toString().substr(-2);
  let months = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
    let days = ["SU", "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA"];
  let tags = ["mon", "d", "y", "h", "m", "s", "day"],
  corr = [months[mo], dy.pad(2), yr, hou.pad(2), min.pad(2), sec.pad(2), days[day]];
  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
    document.getElementById(tags[i]).firstChild.nodeValue = corr[i];
    if(hou < 12){var ampm = "MORNING"}
        if(hou >= 12 && hou <= 18){var ampm = "AFTERNOON"}
        if(hou > 18){var ampm = "EVENING"}
document.getElementById("ampm").innerHTML = ampm;
}
function initClock(clock) {
  updateClock();
  window.setInterval("updateClock()", 1);
}
```

with the numbers dropping in to tagged-up svg in the html:

```
<body onLoad="initClock()">

<div id="horiz">
<svg>
    <g>
        <text><a id="h">22</a>:<a id="m">22</a></text>
        <text><a id="day">WE</a>.<a id="d">DD</a>.<a id="mon">MM</a>.<a id="y">YY</a>.<a id="s">SS</a></text>
        <text>GOOD <a id="ampm">SOMETHING</a></text>
    </g></svg>
</div>
```

but I want the design to totally change for portrait orientation. (I'm using display: none/block on my two ID'd divs on a media query in the css for that.) I've tried to duplicate the script with new names (adding "v") thinking that should do the trick, but the second clock doesn't work:

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(n) {
  for (var r = this.toString(); r.length < n; r = 0 + r);
  return r;
};

function updateClock() {
  let now = new Date();
  let sec = now.getSeconds();
  let min = now.getMinutes();
  let hou = now.getHours();
  let mo = now.getMonth();
  let dy = now.getDate();
    let day = now.getDay();
  let shortYear = now.getFullYear();
  let yr = shortYear.toString().substr(-2);
  let months = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
    let days = ["SU", "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA"];
  let tags = ["mon", "d", "y", "h", "m", "s", "day"],
  corr = [months[mo], dy.pad(2), yr, hou.pad(2), min.pad(2), sec.pad(2), days[day]];
  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
    document.getElementById(tags[i]).firstChild.nodeValue = corr[i];
    if(hou < 12){var ampm = "MORNING"}
        if(hou >= 12 && hou <= 18){var ampm = "AFTERNOON"}
        if(hou > 18){var ampm = "EVENING"}
document.getElementById("ampm").innerHTML = ampm;

  let secv = now.getSeconds();
  let minv = now.getMinutes();
  let houv = now.getHours();
  let mov = now.getMonth();
  let dyv = now.getDate();
    let dayv = now.getDay();
  let shortYearv = now.getFullYear();
  let yrv = shortYearv.toString().substr(-2);
  let monthsv = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
    let daysv = ["SU", "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA"];
  let tagsv = ["monv", "dv", "yv", "hv", "mv", "sv", "dayv"],
  corr = [monthsv[mov], dyv.pad(2), yrv, houv.pad(2), minv.pad(2), secv.pad(2), daysv[dayv]];

  for (var i = 0; i < tagsv.length; i++)
    document.getElementById(tagsv[i]).firstChild.nodeValue = corr[i];
    if(houv < 12){var ampmv = "MORNING"}
        if(houv >= 12 && houv <= 18){var ampmv = "AFTERNOON"}
        if(houv > 18){var ampmv = "EVENING"}
document.getElementById("ampmv").innerHTML = ampmv;
}
function initClock(clock) {
  updateClock();
  window.setInterval("updateClock()", 1);
}
```

with the additional in-html svg:

```
<div id="vert">
    <svg>
            <g>
            
            <text><a id="hv">22</a></text>
            <text><a id="mv">88</a></text>
    
            <text><a id="dv">22</a>.<a id="monv">02</a>.<a id="yv">51</a></text>
            <text><a id="dayv">DAY</a>.<a id="sv">59</a></text>
            
            <text>GOOD <a id="ampmv">SOMETHING</a></text>
            </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: this is a waste of ticks `window.setInterval("updateClock()", 1);` instead have `window.setInterval(updateClock, 1000);`

Comment: Why do you need to change the clock JS functionality at all for a purely design based change? Surely you can keep the layout/design code entirely separate from the Date/Time manipulation?

Comment: Also DRY! No need to have a copy of everything. Just store each clock's current value somwhere, for example in the container as a data-attribute and please move your string arrays outside all functions.

Comment: @mplungjan ah yes, that was a hangover from when I had milliseconds running. Thanks.

Comment: @DBS, if you're meaning I could rejig the design purely in css on the `@media` keeping all the same elements and one-clock html, I can't as clock elements are in a different order and dynamically placed in those orders. Or do you mean something else? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version

I assume we want to keep the month array in case you want the string representation of the month

```js
const pad = num => String(num).padStart(2, "0"),
  months = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"],
  days = ["SU", "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA"],
  tags = ["mon", "d", "y", "h", "m", "s", "day"],
  updateClock = div => {
    let now = new Date();
    let sec = now.getSeconds();
    let min = now.getMinutes();
    let hou = now.getHours();
    let mo = now.getMonth();
    let dy = now.getDate();
    let day = now.getDay();
    let yr = now.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
    corr = [months[mo], pad(dy), yr, pad(hou), pad(min), pad(sec), days[day]];
    tags.forEach((tag, i) => div.querySelector("." + tag).textContent = corr[i]);
    if (hou < 12) {
      var ampm = "MORNING"
    }
    if (hou >= 12 && hou <= 18) {
      var ampm = "AFTERNOON"
    }
    if (hou > 18) {
      var ampm = "EVENING"
    }
    div.querySelector(".ampm").innerHTML = ampm;
  };
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".timer").forEach(div => updateClock(div))
  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<div id="clock1" class="timer">
  <span class="mon"></span>/<span class="d"></span>/<span class="y"></span> (<span class="day"></span>)
  <span class="h"></span>:<span class="m"></span>:<span class="s"></span> <span class="ampm"></span>
  </div>
<div id="clock2" class="timer">
<span class="day"></span> <span class="ampm"></span> at <span class="h"></span>:<span class="m"></span>:<span class="s"></span> on the 
  <span class="mon"></span>/<span class="d"></span>/<span class="y"></span>
  
  </div>
```

Using offsets in seconds stored in data-attribute

```js
const pad = num => String(num).padStart(2, "0"),
  months = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"],
  days = ["SU", "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA"],
  tags = ["mon", "d", "y", "h", "m", "s", "day"],
  updateClock = div => {
    let now = new Date();
    let offset = div.dataset.offset * 1000
    now.setTime(now.getTime() + offset)
    let sec = now.getSeconds();
    let min = now.getMinutes();
    let hou = now.getHours();
    let mo = now.getMonth();
    let dy = now.getDate();
    let day = now.getDay();
    let yr = now.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2);
    corr = [months[mo], pad(dy), yr, pad(hou), pad(min), pad(sec), days[day]];
    tags.forEach((tag, i) => div.querySelector("." + tag).textContent = corr[i]);
    if (hou < 12) {
      var ampm = "MORNING"
    }
    if (hou >= 12 && hou <= 18) {
      var ampm = "AFTERNOON"
    }
    if (hou > 18) {
      var ampm = "EVENING"
    }
    div.querySelector(".ampm").innerHTML = ampm;
  };
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".timer").forEach(div => updateClock(div))
  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<div id="clock1" class="timer" data-offset="176400">
  <span class="mon"></span>/<span class="d"></span>/<span class="y"></span> (<span class="day"></span>)
  <span class="h"></span>:<span class="m"></span>:<span class="s"></span> <span class="ampm"></span>
  </div>
<div id="clock2" class="timer" data-offset="0">
<span class="day"></span> <span class="ampm"></span> at <span class="h"></span>:<span class="m"></span>:<span class="s"></span> on the 
  <span class="mon"></span>/<span class="d"></span>/<span class="y"></span>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Looks like I should be able to adapt that! The first clock is coming up as two days in the future though...

Comment: Yes, that is what I set it to using seconds in offset: `data-offset="176400"`

Comment: Ah yes — sorry — why did you build in an offset? Can I remove all that?

Comment: See update for a version with the same time in all clocks

Comment: life saver. Thank you.